# How do I change a 1 2 light switch to a L1 L2 com light switch?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am replacing the light switches in my house. This one has thrown me a bit, as it is labelled differently to the others.

The new switch (a [BG Electrical Nexus 812-01](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/B006K7S6L2)) is on the left and the old one (of unknown manufacture) is on the right.

[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Qi1eH9r5G99fc7Qf6]

How do I wire the new switch? Do I just put both 1 wires into L1 and both 2 wires into L2? Should I also put the brown wires into common?

Comment: These gray wires raise questions.  Why choose a 2-way switch (US: 3-way) for the new switch?  Now this particular switch, does it control a light that is also controlled from 2 or more other places?  When counting places, be sure to include the ones you don't habitually use or don't know about :)  That being the trick :)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, this switch is one of three - these lights can be controlled at both ends of this hallway and one downstairs. I (foolishly) did not investigate before I purchased replacement switches. Am I unable to use the replacement switch?

Comment: @user263983 New switch (left) is a [BG Electrical Nexus 812-01](https://amazon.co.uk/dp/B006K7S6L2). I have no further information about the old switch (right) other than pictured.

Comment: Sorry, may mistake. New switch is 3-way(US) and the old looks like 4-way. Not straight replaceable. Some changes in wiring may be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Since there are 3 switches involved, you have a ...

You know, I don't know what to call it in the UK.  In the US we call it 4-way, but the UK has different names for these things. Regardless, the *schematic* looks like this:

[image]

*Switch designations are USA naming.  Diagram's 3-way is your 2-way.*

As you can see, the operating principle of multi-way switching is that one *traveler* is live, and the other is not. Each of the switches *exchanges the travelers* - which is pretty easy to do on the ends.

You have the pictured new switch. And I imagine you've been using that *all day* in 1-way (plain) and 2-way (US: 3-way) switches *on the ends*.

But the middle is special.  Here, exchanging the travelers requires 4 terminals - 2 travelers in, and 2 travelers out.  Obviously the 2-way switch you have is simply not up to the task.

You will need to obtain the correct switch for that position.

Comment: It's called an "intermediate switch" in the UK. Also note that in the UK we usually use what you Americans call the "coast method" when wiring up multiway switching.

Comment: In Hebrew, 3way is called "switching switch" (sounds better in Hebrew: מפסק מחליף), and 4way is called "cross switch" (מפתח צלב). I wish whoever wired my corridor knew that. They installed 3 * 3-way switches, with expected results - one switch acting as "master switch" - I thought the light fixtures were borked!